# How to find/grep in Python virtualenv with projectile/helm easier?

Tags: helm, python, files, projectile

How I can customize helm/projectile behaviour to find files and `grep` in `$VIRTUALENV` dir easier? Or maybe I can write some function(s) to `find`/`grep` in `virtualenv` of current project?

Comment: maybe [virtualenvwrapper.el](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el#automatically-activating-a-virtualenv-when-using-projectile) is what you're looking for

Comment: @FelipeLema virtuelenvwrapper.el plugin allow to manipulate with virtualenv's, not to search inside them.